# Installing ubuntu 12.04 as windows application

Tags: system-installation, wubi

I am  currently trying to use Ubuntu without leaving windows. I have downloaded Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

I ran wubi to install it as a windows application but it required the installation of an image of the operating system from the internet and displayed an error message "couldn't retrieve system image" or something like that.

My question is why it need to connect to the internet. I used ubuntu 11.10 and did the same with no problem.

Why it needs to download files from the internet although the file size 695 MB, and contain the windows installer file wubi.exe.

Answer (score 0):

Copy both wubi.exe and the dexktop.iso to the same folder on your windows system and launch wubi from there

Source: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How_do_I_install_Wubi_on_a_machine_with_no_Internet_connection.3F